# Adding a Scriptable Object to the Scene

Tags: c#, unity

Suppose a `Scriptable Object` e.g. `NewWeapon.asset` with variables such as `name`, `description`, `price` etc.

I've also added a `public GameObject weaponObject;` so that I can drag and drop the 3D model related to this weapon.

Since `Scriptable Objects` cannot be added in a scene, how can I add a `GameObject` in the scene with an attached script that will *draw* data from the `NewWeapon.asset` and display the `3DModel` already specified and load up the rest of the variables?

My goal is to create a script `Item.cs` which will be attached to a `GameObject` in the scene and then based on the current `ScriptableObject` load its name, stats and `3Dmodel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScriptableObject`s are not components, so you can't add them with "Add Component". But they can be properties of components.

When you create a variable `public ScriptableObject foo` (or of a class which extends ScriptableObject) in a MonoBehaviour and then add that MonoBehaviour to the scene, you get a box for it in the inspector to which you can drag-and-drop a ScriptableObject.

Example script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ThingWhichHasAScriptableObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public ScriptableObject assignedAsset;

}
```

A GameObject with that component in the editor:

[image: ScriptableObject]

You can now drag your `NewWeapon.asset` into the "Assigned Asset" slot and then interact with it from the `ThingWhichHasAScriptableObject` script.

Regarding displaying a 3d model assigned to the ScriptableObject: Just assigning the ScriptableObject to a GameObject in your scene won't cause it to be rendered. You will have to `Instantiate` that 3d model at runtime.

Comment: Hmm, so if I want to access its name I 'd say `foo.name = "blah";` right? About the 3Dmodel, I know that it will not be rendered by simply assigning it. If you read my edited question above you will see that I want a _generic_ block of code that would read which 3dmodel is assigned and then display/add it in the scene. Is this something that can be done or am I in deep waters?

Comment: @Karaflakos Yes, that would work. You would define your Item as a `class ItemData : ScriptableObject` and declare the `foo` variable in your component of type `ItemData`.

Comment: So I've done what you said and it works perfectly! Any idea on how the _add the 3Dmodel in the scene_ thing would work?

Comment: @Karaflakos That depends on what your definition of "3Dmodel" is. Is it already a full-fledged `GameObject` with a `MeshFilter` and a `MeshRenderer` with `Material`s assigned? Or is it just a `Mesh`?

Comment: It's a prefab from an asset I downloaded which is ready to use. It only needs to be added in the scene.

Comment: @Karaflakos Then I would call `Instantiate(ItemData.model, transform.position, transform.rotation)` in the `Start()` method of the MonoBehaviour which has the ScriptableObject.